# Multinomial Probit Representation of a Categorical Variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $C$ be a $J$-dimensional categorical variable with probabilities $p_1,\dots,p_J$, where $p_j>0$ $\forall j$.

Next let $\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_J$ be $iid$ random variables from the  distribution $F_\epsilon$. For $\mu\in\mathbb{R}^J$ and $j=1,\dots,J$, define $G_j(\mu,F_\epsilon)=Pr(\mu_j+\epsilon_j\ge \mu_k+\epsilon_k, \forall k)$.

For what distributions $F_\epsilon$ is it the case that for any such $C$ there exists a $\mu$ with $G_j(\mu,F_\epsilon)=p_j$ $\forall j$?

Clearly it's the case when the $\epsilon_j$ are standard Gumbel random variables; then by construction $Pr(\ln(p_j)+\epsilon_j\ge\ln(p_k)+\epsilon_k)=p_j$. I think of this as the "multinomial logit representation of $C$."

I have a strong intuition (and indeed, find it to be true in every simulation I've tried) that it's also the case for $\epsilon_j\stackrel{iid}{\sim}N(0,1)$, which I would think of as the "multinomial *probit* representation of $C$." But I'm getting stuck constructing the $\mu$ or showing they must exist implicitly. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now think I have a more general proof for any $J$ and any eliptically-distributed $\epsilon=(\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_J)$.

For such (without loss, zero-located) $\epsilon$, we can write

$G_j=Pr(\tilde{\mu}_j-\tilde{\mu}_k>\epsilon_k-\epsilon_j,\forall k)=\int_{\infty}^{\tilde{\mu}_j-\tilde{\mu}_{-j}}|\Sigma_{j}|^{1/2}g(t'\Sigma_{j}t)dt$,

for some positive real-valued function $g(\cdot)$, where $\tilde{\mu}_{-j}=[\tilde{\mu}_1,\dots,\tilde{\mu}_{j-1},\tilde{\mu}_{j+1},\dots,\tilde{\mu}_{J-1},0]'$ and $\tilde{\mu}_j=\mu_j-\mu_J$. Here $\Sigma_{j}$ is the dispersion matrix of $[\epsilon_j-\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_j-\epsilon_{j-1},\epsilon_j-\epsilon_{j+1},\dots,\epsilon_j-\epsilon_J]'$.

Let $\nabla G$ denote the square Jacobian of $(G_1,\dots,G_{J-1})'$ with respect to $(\tilde{\mu}_1,\dots,\tilde{\mu}_{J-1})'$. By inspection, $\nabla G$ is everywhere a strictly-diagonally dominant L-matrix; by the Levy-Desplanques theorem it is thus everywhere invertible. Moreover it is evident that $(G_1(\tilde{\mu}),\dots,G_{J-1}(\tilde{\mu}))'$ is a proper mapping from $\mathbb{R}^{J-1}$ to $P^{J-1}$, the set of the first $J-1$ elements of vectors in the open $J-1$ standard simplex. Thus, by Hadamard's global inverse theorem, for any $(p_1,\dots,p_{J-1})$ there exists a *unique* $\tilde{\mu}^*$ such that $G_j(\tilde{\mu^*})=p_j$ for each $j$. For any constant $k$, $\mu=\tilde{\mu}^*+k$ thus satisfies $G_j(\mu)=p_j$ for each $j$.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I now have a proof for the $J=3$ case (the $J=2$ case is trivial; just set $\mu_1=\sqrt{2}\Phi^{-1}(p_1)$ and $\mu_2=0$). Does the following make sense? Presumably the same logic holds in the general case...

Set $\mu_3=0$ and consider $G_3(\mu,N(0,1))=Pr(-\mu_1\ge \epsilon_3-\epsilon_1, -\mu_2\ge \epsilon_3-\epsilon_1)$. Clearly its partial derivatives are nonzero and since $Pr(-\mu\ge \epsilon_3-\epsilon_1, -\mu\ge \epsilon_3-\epsilon_1)$ is strictly decreasing from $\mathbb{R}$ onto $(0,1)$, there exists a $\bar{\mu}$ such that $Pr(-\bar{\mu}\ge \epsilon_3-\epsilon_1, -\bar{\mu}\ge \epsilon_3-\epsilon_1)=p_3$. Thus (I think) we can invoke the implicit function theorem to say there exists a $\mu_2(\mu_1)$ such that $$Pr(-\mu_1\ge \epsilon_3-\epsilon_1, -\mu_2(\mu_1)\ge \epsilon_3-\epsilon_1)=p_3.$$
By differentiating this we find $\mu_2^\prime(\mu_1)<0$ for all $\mu_1$.

Now consider $G_1((\mu_1,\mu_2(\mu_1),0)^\prime,N(0,1))=Pr(\mu_1-\mu_2(\mu_1)\ge\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1, \mu_1\ge \epsilon_3-\epsilon_1)$. By inspection this is a strictly increasing function from $\mathbb{R}$ onto $(0,1)$ so there must exist a $\mu_1^*$ with $G_1((\mu_1^*,\mu_2(\mu_1^*),0)^\prime,N(0,1))=p_1$. But then we'd also have (by construction) $G_3((\mu_1^*,\mu_2(\mu_1^*),0),N(0,1))=p_3$ and $G_2((\mu_1^*,\mu_2(\mu_1^*),0),N(0,1))=1-p_3-p_1=p_2$, so we're done.